# pgfplots: Is it possible to control the curvature of smooth plots?

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I'd like the plot below to look a little rounder and more "puffy", a little less angular. Is there some option that will allow me to control this easily?

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.10}

\begin{document}

    \begin{tikzpicture}

        \begin{axis}[
            axis lines=left,
            scaled ticks=false,
            xtick=\empty,
            ytick=\empty,
            enlargelimits=0.1,
        ]

        \addplot[smooth] coordinates {(5,100) (10,50) (25,70) (40,30) (60,100)}; 

        \end{axis}

    \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Add `yscale=.5,`, for example to your axis options. This will make your figure rectangular, though.

Comment: I don't think it is an easy job. You may add more points instead.

Comment: If you know what you want a graph to look like and you want to produce that by specifying some points it goes through, I suggest that you use Hobby's algorithm. This can be done via the `hobby` package (tikz) or by using Metapost or Asymptote (which both have Hobby's algorithm built in).

Comment: @CharlesStaats Didn't know about `hobby`; thanks for that. Seems like it would require tweaking in/out angles for each bump, though, which is more work than I want to do.

Comment: @AboAmmar I can't squash the figure in that way.

Comment: IIRC, TikZ uses quadratic splines to produce smooth lines. There is not a lot you can do to affect the solution

Comment: @grendelsdad: Using `hobby` emphatically does *not* require tweaking in/out angles. It is possible to tweak these, but doing so consistently more or less negates the whole point of the package, which is to do a better job than the default `smooth` option of drawing smooth curves *without* such tweaking.

Comment: @CharlesStaats: Yes, but if I want to be picky about the "puffiness" I would need to tweak the angles (or some other parameters). For example when I tried it on some sample points that looked (almost) fine in a `smooth` plot, the `hobby` result looked almost like not a function (i.e., >1 y-value for some x-values). The packages seems amazing for drawing curves on the plane but might require too much customization for drawing functions the way I want to.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Play around with `tension` key

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    axis lines=left,scaled ticks=false,xtick=\empty,ytick=\empty,enlargelimits=0.1,
]

\addplot[smooth,tension=1] coordinates {(5,100) (10,50) (25,70) (40,30) (60,100)}; 

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

But in general avoid artificial smoothness in your plots. They basically convey made-up precision. Instead try to add more coordinates along the way.

[image]

Comment: I think `tension` will work. I'm not sure I agree about adding artificial smoothness, at least for this application. I'm just trying to "sketch" a curve, not to plot an actual function, so IMO there's nothing inherently more made-up about the curve with `tension=1` vs. the default. Adding more coordinates will make the plot look less smooth unless I am very careful about placement, and since this is just a sketch, I don't want to have to be that careful.

Comment: @grendelsdad Then you need to *draw* a curve and not *plot* it. pgfplots is not the right tool here.

Comment: Why? I have many figures in my document; some are precise plots of actual functions and some are sketches of functions. If pgfplots does the sketches as well as plain TikZ and is easier, why not use it? Why force myself to implement axes and other plot-related elements manually in TikZ (and reproduce all the styles that pgfplots uses)? Seems like an artificial distinction.

Comment: @grendelsdad I meant you need to use `draw` not `addplot`. Convenience and utility are not interchangeable concepts. TikZ also has a very comprehensive visualization library.

Comment: I see -- makes sense.